# Modules to create submenu with custom markup

Tags: routes

I have a question about how to create menu with full custom markup. Custom markup is applied not to menu items, but to entire submenu.

An example of such menu is provided below:

[image: Example]

As you can see, submenu items have different visual attributes. And they are arranged like in a grid layout.

I think, it's possible to catch mouse over events and show html element with the submenu content, when user points cursor at submenu.

But, if you know any Drupal modules, that allow to implement such a feature, or simplify this task, it will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Out these two modules..: [TB Mega Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu) and [Nice Menus](https://www.drupal.org/project/nice_menus)

Here is a post which lists some of them  [Mega Menu modules for Drupal](http://megadrupal.com/blog/7-mega-menu-modules-for-drupal)

Answer (score 0):

Well I did this using [Menu attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module. Simply add any Class or Id to any menu item you want to style.